# Justify last line of UITextView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextview, justify

I am working on a book like project. Where there are list of paragraphs on multiple pages that you can scroll through. I create separate `UITextView` for every single page and set it as justified to create that book-like experience. Unfortunately last line of `UITextView` is not justified (because I am using new `UITextView` for every single page). So in fact `UITextView` is behaving correctly. But as my paragraph continue on next page, I would like it to express that by justifying the last line. I am using `UITextView` to provide user an option to select and copy parts of text.

[This is how it looks now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzg6h.png)

[This is what is expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57aX6.png)

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @PGDev I was not able to find any code that can affect only last line. No idea how to deal with it. I can only influence other rows by setting textAlignment property.

Answer (score 0):

I added a category on UITextView to perform the calculations we need for the last line. This can either be separate .h/.m files or placed at the top of the .m file where you need to use it. Note that this operates on the attributedText and textContainer properties. The attributedText property is set (as of iOS7) even when you only set the text property on the UITextView. The textContainer property defines the size of the area where the UITextView will render its text, but you may need this be a little different, if you are using constrains to lay out the UITextView.

```
@interface UITextView (LastLineRange)

- (NSRange) lastLineRange;

@end

@implementation UITextView (LastLineRange)

- (NSRange)lastLineRange
{
    // calculate the bounds for the text rendered in the UITextView
    CGSize textSize = [self.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:self.textContainer.size
                                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        context:nil].size;

    // we care about the last line, so get the start and end points along the bottom of the bounds
    UITextPosition* start = [self characterRangeAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, textSize.height)].start;
    UITextPosition* end = [self characterRangeAtPoint:CGPointMake(textSize.width, textSize.height)].end;

    // turn the text positions into indices we can make a range with
    NSInteger startLoc = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument
                                       toPosition:start];

    // this should not be 'endOfDocument', but the end that we calculated above,
    // since this represents the end of the visible text
    NSInteger endLoc = [self offsetFromPosition:start
                                     toPosition:end];

    return NSMakeRange(startLoc, endLoc);
}

@end
```

This is how I used the category to get the last line and apply a right-aligned paragraph style to it. I've tried to add comments to make it clear what is happening. I just roughed out the actual UITextView, so it's not as pretty as your example, but should give you the idea.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];

    // used for the main, left-aligned text
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* pStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    pStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    pStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    // used for the last line, which will be right-aligned
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* lastStyle = [pStyle mutableCopy];
    lastStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 4.0,
                                  50.0,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);

    UITextView* page = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:pageFrame
                                            textContainer:nil];

    page.scrollEnabled = false;
    page.editable = false;

    // attributes for main text
    NSDictionary* lAlignedAttrs = @{
                                    NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pStyle
                                   };

    // attributes for the last line of text
    NSDictionary* rAlignedAttrs = @{
                                    NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : lastStyle,
                                    // only added this to highlight the last line changes
                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
                                   };

    // needs to be mutable, so we can set attributes at certain ranges
    NSMutableAttributedString* text1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                                                    attributes:lAlignedAttrs];

    // now set the attributed text as content for the UITextView, since
    // we will use the category for finding the last line
    page.attributedText = text1;

    // here, we ensure that the last line will be considered a new paragraph
    // so the paragraph style changes we make will take effect
    NSInteger insertionIndex = page.lastLineRange.location;
    if ( [text1.string characterAtIndex:insertionIndex] != '\n' )
    {
        [text1 insertAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]
                              atIndex:insertionIndex];
    }

    // apply right-aligned paragraph style over the range of the last line
    [text1 setAttributes:rAlignedAttrs
                   range:page.lastLineRange];

    // we have altered the attributed text, so need to set the new text
    // as the content for the UITextView
    page.attributedText = text1;

    [self.view addSubview:page];
}


@end
```

Here is what I achieved with this:
[image: Right-Aligned Last Line Text]

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to include what is expected. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: @svojtko I edited to show the results of what I got working for you. Please let me know if I've misunderstood what you meant.